# Can I hide the title bar of MPlayer in gnome?

Tags: gnome, gtk, window, mplayer

I'm on a 10.04 machine with MPlayer, version SVN-r1.0~rc3+svn20090426-4.4.3.

When you invoke MPlayer from the command line to show a file, it displays the file within a window. This bar has a title, "MPlayer".

[image]

How can I disable this bar, entirely? I don't want to remove the title only, but the complete window bar. It's probably not an MPlayer option, but rather something with the window toolkit?

Comment: Sorry, didn't catch that earlier — yes, I want to remove the complete window decoration, to more or less have a borderless video playing.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

If it's just for MPlayer you could use the `-noborder` argument. [image: ;)]

```
mplayer -noborder my_video.ogg
```

[image: Screenshot of How fast.ogg]

As a more general option, if you're using Compiz (default), you can:

1. Install and launch the [*CompizConfig Settings Manager*](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/compizconfig-settings-manager) [image: (Install)]
2. Select the *Window Decoration* plugin and hit the "plus" sign next to "Decoration Windows".
3. Describe the type of window you do *not* want title bars on with an "And" relationship, and mark "Invert". For example:

[image: Window Class: MPlayer, And relation, Inverted]

Click "Add" and enjoy!

Comment: Does the first method work only for MPlayer, or only for .ogg files? It failed to work for a .avi file with Totem.

Comment: Seems like option #1 does the trick already — I'll check tomorrow to be sure. Thanks for the great answer!

Comment: @SatchitBhogle The '-noborder' switch is an mplayer-specific feature.

Comment: What if we want to do it with some other app - any straightforward way?

Answer (score 6):

One can remove the border of all windows, it is however a little hacky. I described the process a bit at:

http://grumbel.blogspot.com/2011/06/forcing-fullscreen-in-linux-for-apps.html

And have some code floating around at:

https://github.com/Grumbel/fullscreen-tools

Using the code from the git repository you can do:

```
./windowtool.py --decorations 0 ACTIVE
```

Which will deactivate the border, using 1 instead of 0 will reactivate it. ACTIVE refers to the window that has currently the focus, you can also give the window id which you can obtain via:

```
wmctrl -l
```

PS: The code isn't pretty and the README in there is a bit out of date.

Comment: I removed any unrelated stuff and created a tiny script that simply toggles the titlebar of the active window, here: https://gist.github.com/1815146 (I bind it to super+r in xfce keyboard settings, works nicely for youtube popouts along with always-on-top)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `-title` option:

```
mplayer -title ' ' file.avi
```

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't being clear. I wanted to get rid of the border entirely (see Jacob's answer above).

Answer (score 1):

Here's how to remove the title bar, that should work with almost all window managers in X11 :

```
xprop -name 'My window name' -format _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 32i -set _MOTIF_WM_HINTS 2
```

where `My window name` is your window name.

You can specify the window id instead, with the `-id` option.

If you omit the `-name` option, you will have to select the window whose title bar you want removed, by clicking on it.